Is it possible to airdrop solana-tokens distribute-spl-tokens without tokens on mint account?
I was trying to make an Airdrop (mass distro) of our $TOKEN (SPL).
First we wrote a disperser using TS. And it worked (very slow) but for whatever reason 40 Tx (transactions) failed, I tried again several times but was getting same failures.
We're using RPC Ironforge proxy with (Quicknode, Syndica, Chainstack, Alchemy, Helius).
So I decided to find a way and found the tool from Solana:
solana-tokens distribute-spl-tokens
So I made a run and got an error:
solana-tokens -url https://rpc.ironforge.network/mainnet?apiKey= distribute-spl-tokens --db-path data/airDrop/24/07/distribute-spl-tokens_log.yml --fee-payer accounts/airdrop.json --input-csv data/airDrop/24/07/holders_1.csv --from someTOKENaCAuADDRESS --owner accounts/mint.json
Error: ProgramError(InvalidAccountData)

In our case our mint account is not used and has no authority over TOKEN. It also doesn't have any tokens (TOKEN || SOL). And the distribution using TS scripts I was doing from the Airdrops Wallet (just a wallet created and filled with SOL and TOKEN).
So is it possible to do that with solana-tokens distribute-spl-tokens ? Or it's possible to do only from the mint account?

solana-tokens distribute-spl-tokens works by distributing from a pre-funded token account, so you'll need to have all the tokens in a token account already. The --owner must be the owner of the --from account, which is someTOKENaCAuADDRESS in your example, and not the mint keypair. So as long as you have the owner keypair, and you've minted all the tokens into someTOKENaCAuADDRESS, you should be good to go!

If the --owner must be owner of --from it only can be mint account. As someTOKENaCAuADDRESS is the CA of the SPL token. Or you mean that in --from it should be a token account with only the SPL token to be distributed?

I mean the second -- --from must be a token account
